# C++ Unicode for Color16 Values

Tags: c++, unicode

This has been one huge headache. Ive googled everything and found very little, and have little knowledge on unicode, learned a bit from the searching. What I am needing is really simple, right? A struct I am using requires COLOR16.

So I know 0x0000 and 0x00FF is 0 to 255, which for COLOR16 is useless.

The four zeros each can represent 0 to 15 Ive seen.

I know COLOR16 represents all 16^4 colors.

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert say, (R:100; G:35; B:42) to a unicode value.

I could really use some info on this, or a tutorial or anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Unicode is character encoding, and has nothing to do with color. And what is a COLOR16? Are you using a specific graphics library?

Comment: Color and Unicode have nothing at all to do with each other. Unicode is a system for representing **text**, not color.

Comment: Perhaps he has [synethesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia).

Comment: Normally not supposed to respond to the above, but, I have to say this. Clearly I stated that "have little knowledge on unicode" I have no idea what any of it is, that is why I asked the question. From the first paragraph on I described what I was looking at, minus the COLOR16, should have known what I was... thinking/ looking at? Just stating. I do appreciate all of the sarcasm, you did not help me one bit. Maybe if I was psychic, I could have  posted the question as: "I know what unicode is, so I need to know about it." -Sarcasm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know what you're looking for.  You're just asking the wrong way.  You mean a `short` value, not a Unicode value.  The common name for this is RGB565.  That means 5-bits for red, 6 for green and 5 for blue.

That adds up to 16 bits.  You pack the bits in like this:

```
unsigned short val = ((r<<8) & 0xf800) | ((g<<3) & 0x07e0) | (b>>3);
```

The bits are like this:

```
R  00000000 12345xxx  ->  12345000 00000000  (shift left by 8 and masked)
G  00000000 123456xx  ->  00000123 45600000  (shift left by 3 and masked)
B  00000000 12345xxx  ->  00000000 00012345  (shift right by 3, no mask required)
```

Obviously information is lost in this process.  You are just taking the most significant bits of the colour and using that.  It's like lossy compression, but pretty good for video when you don't notice the loss of colour definition as much.  The reason green gets the extra bit is because human eyes are more sensitive to colours in that spectrum.

Comment: I am interested to know how the confusion with Unicode arose though.

Comment: @john In the context of the question, I'm pretty sure it's just a confusion over the size of the datatype, with the assumption that a 16-bit number is always a "unicode character".

Comment: Thanks for the response and knowing what I am talking about.

I tried to implement it, but I need the R G B's separate but I could only get the R channel to work.

    `int r = 100; int g = 40; int b = 200; // (the 0-255 values)`

    `vertex.Red   = R; // ((r<<8) & 0xf800)`

    `vertex.Green = G; // ((g<<3) & 0x07e0)`

    `vertex.Blue  = B; // (b>>3)`

Is what I had tried, but ended up as black.

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen a similar case where 15 bits are used, 5 for each color in RGB, and one to signal 50% transparency. Ultima Online uses that as color indexes.

Comment: @EvanCarslake It doesn't come out black (see http://ideone.com/p9CpZR), but it seems we were mislead by your comment *"COLOR16 represents all 16^4 colors"*.  What you wanted was to scale each colour element.  If you had shown the structure you were using, this would have been obvious.  Glad you found your solution in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a random example that had the solution in it. This takes a COLORREF and extracts 16bit colors for the TRIVERTEX struct:

`vertex[1].Red   = GetRValue(clrStart)<<8;
vertex[1].Green = GetGValue(clrStart)<<8;
vertex[1].Blue  = GetBValue(clrStart)<<8;`

Comment: For scaling a colour across the full range, use this: `(r << 8) | r`, *etc*.  This ensures your whites are actually white (`0xff` --> `0xffff`) instead of almost white (`0xff` --> `0xff00`).

Answer (score 0):

It is misleading in the Windows API if that is what you are asking, RGBA all "COLOR16" references should be stored as byte [0-255] for each channel in the TRIVERTEX structure. though I have seen most use short values which are 8 bits

Red   [0-255]; <= byte
Green [0-255]; <= byte
Blue  [0-255]; <= byte
Alpha [0-255]; <= byte

Microsoft: what can you say